# Custom counter steps twice when invoked from caption using caption package

Tags: numbering, captions, counters

I made a custom counter with a custom command that steps the counter and sets an automatic label for it. However, when invoking this from a caption AND using the `caption` package, my counter steps two times. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcounter{example}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theexample}{\thechapter{}.\arabic{example}}
\providecommand{\example}[1]{\refstepcounter{example}\label{ex:#1}{\theexample}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{\protect\example{my_example}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If I comment out the line `\usepackage{caption}`, I get the right results.

Is this a bug, or am I doing here some very basic mistake?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could get a double evaluation without the caption package as well (depending on the length of the text). The `caption` package provides a way to ensure the text is only evaluated once:

```
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
```

Answer (score 9):

As already said by David the caption text will usually be evaluated once or twice, depending on the length of the caption text. (So if you make your caption text longer than one line you'll run into the same problem, even without `caption` package.)

To make things more consistent the `caption` package always evaluates the caption text twice.

Using the `caption` package with option `singlelinecheck=false` (as suggested by David) will switch off the first evaluation but it will switch off the single-line-feature of the `caption` package as well, giving you left-aligned (instead of centered) short captions.

If this is ok for you this is the easiest method to solve your problem. But if you would like to keep the single-line-feature we have to take a look at the internals of the `caption` package:

During the first evaluation (to determine the length of the caption text) `\caption@prepareslc` will be used, so one can get rid of side-effects of the double evaluation by extending this macro.

An example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcounter{example}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theexample}{\thechapter{}.\arabic{example}}
\newcommand{\stepexample}{\refstepcounter{example}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\example}[1]{\stepexample\label{ex:#1}{\theexample}}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\caption@prepareslc{%
  \renewcommand{\stepexample}{\caption@l@stepcounter{example}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{\example{my_example}}
\end{figure}

\ref{ex:my_example}

\end{document}
```

What have I done here:

- I have outsourced the incrementation of the `example` counter to `\stepexample` so I can re-define this one later on.
- I have extended `\caption@prepareslc` so the `example` counter will only be incremented locally during the evaluation of the caption text length. (Not incrementing it at all seems to be a working solution as well, but this will give you an improper measurement of the caption text length since `1` will have a different length than `2` and so on.)
- I use the internal macro `\caption@l@stepcounter` for local incrementation of the `example` counter.

But why don't we re-define `\refstepcounter` to `\caption@l@stepcounter` within `\caption@prepareslc`? In fact this was done by some `caption` package versions since this seems to be an easy global solution for all counters, but I have to drop this solution since some code (offered by other packages) was not happy with this patch of `\refstepcounter` at all.