# Caption package messing with Endnotes package

Tags: captions, endnotes

I'm facing a weird problem with `caption` and `endnotes` packages. I have some figures and their caption contains endnotes. However, at each call of `\endnote`, the endnote counter is incremented by 2 instead of 1. It should be 1, 2, 3... but I'm getting 2, 4, 6...

The problem is related to the `caption` package. If I remove it, problem solved!
However, I would like to find a way to solve this issue without removing any package. Can you help?

MWE with the problem:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{endnotes}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption[caption for toc]{figure caption\endnote{endnote A}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption[caption for toc]{figure caption\endnote{endnote B}}
\end{figure}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I also load `subcaption` package, the same problem occurs.

Comment: It seems that `caption` package redefines the `\stepcounter` command.

Comment: Yes, but if you use `\footnote` instead of `\endnote` the footnote counters are correct

Comment: I've found the solution here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127935/75142