# Endnotes in figures are weird

Tags: floats, endnotes

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside, final, headsepline]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage[perpage, multiple]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{Linkverzeichnis}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
\section{Grundlagen}

Bla bla bla Link\endnote{url1}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\caption[Short caption without endnote to avoid errors]{Blubber. (Quelle\endnote{url2})}
\end{figure}

Bla bla bla Link\endnote{url3}

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: wrong endnots counter]

Instead of the endnotes counting

```
1. url1
2. url2
3. url3
```

I get

```
1. url1
3. url2
4. url3
```

or alternatively:

```
1. url1
2. url2
3. url2
4. url3
```

In this case you can trigger the last one by commenting out the `\usepackage[bf]{caption}` line, but I get both in my text. I already figured out that this happens if there is an endnote inside a float, but I really don't know why.

How can I fix this?

## Edit:

Based on the solution provided in the accepted answer, I built the following commands for future reuse:

```
\newcommand{\endnoteouter}[1]{\sbox0{\endnotemark}\endnotetext{\sloppy#1}}
\newcommand{\endnoteinner}{\usebox0}
```

Declare the endnote with `\endnoteouter{Text}` before the figure and call it with `\endnoteinner` at the correct place. If there are multiple endnotes in a figure, an argument could be passed to specify the box number.

Comment: A simple solution is using `\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}` see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127935/124842 .

Comment: @Bobyandbob while being a nice solution this seems to break the `\centering` of the `\caption`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the answer provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43794/117050) you can get this working like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside, final, headsepline]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage[perpage, multiple]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{Linkverzeichnis}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
\section{Grundlagen}

Bla bla bla Link\endnote{url1}
\sbox0{\endnotemark}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\caption[Short caption without endnote to avoid errors]{Blubber.
    (Quelle\usebox0)}
\end{figure}
\endnotetext{url2}

Bla bla bla Link\endnote{url3}

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image: results]

To the question why this happens: The contents of the `\endnote` might get evaluated twice (because the `\caption` is evaluated twice) resulting in an additional incrementation of `endnote`-counter.

EDIT: As requested here is a (very ugly) command, that might ease the process:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside, final, headsepline]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage[perpage, multiple]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{Linkverzeichnis}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[bf]{caption}

\newcommand\mycaption[4]{
    \sbox0{\endnotemark}
    \caption[#1]{#2\usebox0#3}
    \endnotetext{#4}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Grundlagen}

Bla bla bla Link\endnote{url1}
\sbox0{\endnotemark}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\caption[Short caption without endnote to avoid errors]{Blubber.
    (Quelle\usebox0)}
\end{figure}
\endnotetext{url2}

Bla bla bla Link\endnote{url3}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\mycaption{Short caption without endnote to avoid errors}{Blubber. (Quelle}{)}{url4}
\end{figure}

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

The syntax of this command would be:

`\mycaption[<short caption for lot/lof>]{<caption until the endnote-mark>}{<caption after the endnote-mark>}{<content of the endnotemark>}`

EDIT 2:
If the `endnotemark` should always be at the same spot (Quelle#) you might change the command to:

```
\newcommand\mycaption[3][]{
    \sbox0{\endnotemark}
    \ifx&#1&
        \caption[#2]{#2 (Quelle\usebox0)}
    \else
        \caption[#1]{#2 (Quelle\usebox0)}
    \fi
    \endnotetext{#3}
}
```

And use it this way: `\mycaption[<short caption>]{<caption>}{<endnote text>}`
If you leave out the `<short caption>` the caption without "(Quelle#)" is displayed in the `\listof...`-commands.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is there a way to put this into a new command to integrate it into larger texts more easily?

Comment: @piegames see my edit. But it is a ugly command.

Comment: @piegames I added another example of the new command which might be better but is less versatile.

Comment: Just found out your method has a little drawback: It does not respect the text formatting in the float. Fortunately, this was only an issue in subfigures for me.

Comment: @piegames That's because the content of the box is not set inside of a caption. You might change the line `\sbox0{\endnotemark}` to something containing the required text formatting, e.g. `\sbox0{\small\endnotemark}`.